# Type cast Int to String in PHP?

Tags: php, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prefix a positive number with plus sign in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682397/how-to-prefix-a-positive-number-with-plus-sign-in-php)

I have code similar to this

```
$points = -2;
$points = +2;
```

I want to display them as strings including the - or +. This works fine for the - but not for the +

I have tried this to try to get the positive sign

```
echo (string)$points;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No this seemed to make the minus sign go as well.

Comment: And anyway Daniel A White, read the date posted on that question. It was over a year ago. "asked Apr 21 '10 at 11:22"

Comment: @SeanHJenkins: "Duplicate" simply means "this has been covered in a previous post", not necessarily that *you* have asked this question before. The date is irrelevant. It's not a bad thing, it's meant to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positive sign is omitted because if a number isn't negative, it's positive.

You'll have to use a function of sorts:

```
function format_sign($number) {
  $number = int($number);

  if ($number > 0) {
    return "+" . $number;
  } else {
    return $number;
  }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
$n = -10;

echo format_sign($n);
```

---

Nope, I lied. `sprintf()` seems like a better solution:

```
function format_sign($number) {
  return sprintf("%+d", $number);
}
```

Comment: Not to be confused with `number_format` which is a real function.

Comment: PHP has way too many functions...

Answer (score 1):

As Kerrek stated, you can use printf, or you can use a ternary statement:

`echo ($points > 0 ? '+' . $points : $points);`

For using printf, that'd be:  `printf('%+d', $points);`
Using printf means that you can also specify a designated width and number of decimal places as well, which may come in handy if you're trying to get specific formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follwoing:

```
printf('%+d', $points);
```

See the exmaples [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for more explanation.