# Print a sequence of numbers in PHP with the correct (+/-) sign

Tags: php, string-formatting

I need to print some numbers in a sequence with + and - between them. However, I don't know beforehand which number is going to be positive and which is going to be negative. Currently, I echo them like this:

```
echo "$a + $b + $c + $d + $e + $f";
```

Let's say the values of `$a` to `$f` are all positive. I will get something like: `5 + 10 + 12 + 18 + 9 + 7`.

However, if some of the values are negative, I will get something like `5 + -10 + 12 + -18 + 9 + - 7`. The ideal output in this case would have been `5 - 10 + 12 - 18 + 9 - 7`.

Please not that I don't want to calculate the final result of addition or subtraction. I just want to print it all on the webpage with correct signs.

I could do so by writing 6 nested `if()` blocks but that seems like a lot of work and doing it every time will be error prone. Is there anything clever that I can do to output the right sign.

Comment: What should it look like if the first number is negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to correct the operator appearance in the final string:

```
$s = '5 + -10 + 12 + -18 + 9 + - 7'; // result of interpolation or concatenation
$s = str_replace('+ -', '- ', $s);
// => "5 - 10 + 12 - 18 + 9 -  7"
```

If this is possible for you, this is as fast as it gets -- no looping (in php), no treating each number one at a time with a conditional.  If you loop anyway, I'd recommend @Phils suggestion with `array_reduce` -- functional style php -- adapted to your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. This seems to be the most efficient and easiest way of changing signs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Need to check for each variable manually like this:

```
echo "$a " . ($b < 0 ? " - " . abs($b) : " + $b") . ($c < 0 ? " - " . abs($c) : " + $c") . ($d < 0 ? " - " . abs($d) : " + $d") . ($e < 0 ? " - " . abs($e) : " + $e") . ($f < 0 ? " - " . abs($f) : " + $f");
```

Comment: Thanks @Lovepreet. I was looking for some other way that will keep the original echo statement short and simple. Your way is still much better than using 6 different `if()` blocks. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use php sprintf function.

```
function formatNum($num){
    return sprintf("%+d",$num);
}
```

or

```
function formatNum($num) {
  $num = (int) $num; // or (float) if you'd rather
  return (($num >= 0) ? '+' : '-') . $num; // implicit cast back to string
}
```

for more detail please read it :- http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: SO reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682397/how-to-prefix-a-positive-number-with-plus-sign-in-php

Answer (score 1):

try this

`$a = 10;`

`$b=-20;`

`$text = $a." ".$b;`

`$text= str_replace(" ", "+", $text);`

`echo $text;`

OUTPUT

**10+-20**

Answer (score 1):

Put the numbers in an array and use `array_reduce` to create the string

```
$numbers = [5, -10, 12, -18, 9, -7];
$first = array_shift($numbers);

echo array_reduce($numbers, function($str, $num) {
    return $str . sprintf(' %s %d', $num < 0 ? '-' : '+', abs($num)); 
}, $first);
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/1034635

This way you can handle an arbitrary amount of numbers without duplicating logic everywhere.