# php display positive number with '+' sign

Tags: php

I have a simple calculation using php below, i want to get the sum of total displayed with '+' if the number is positive, eg. '+121', can it be done?

```
$total = $row["subtotal1"] - $row["subtotal2"];

echo ".$total."
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prefix a positive number with plus sign in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682397/how-to-prefix-a-positive-number-with-plus-sign-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper function as following:

```
function getPositiveOrNegative($number){
  return ($number >= 0) ? '+' : '';
}

$number = 10;
echo getPositiveOrNegative($number).$number.'<br/>';

$number = -20;
echo getPositiveOrNegative($number).$number.'<br/>';

$number = 0;
echo getPositiveOrNegative($number).$number.'<br/>';
```

Output:
+10
-20
+0

Answer (score 2):

You can echo + sign if your total is greater than 0: `echo ($total > 0 ? '+' : '').$total;`

```
$total = 2;
echo ($total > 0 ? '+' : '').$total; // +2

$total = 0;
echo ($total > 0 ? '+' : '').$total; // 0

$total = -1;
echo ($total > 0 ? '+' : '').$total; // -1
```